# Virtuemart 3.0, Distinct prices for different languages

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, virtuemart, multilingual

I'm with an problem, that I want to put in VirtueMart 3 with two type of coins(cash) each one goes to one distinct language, for example:

```
English (en-GB): Dollar 
Portuguese (pt-BR): Real
```

When a visitor goes to my shop, if he's from U.S the prices of my products will display the price that I've put for Dollar coin, if he's from Brazil the prices of my products will display the price for Real coin.

**Example:**

```
Product A
Price in Dollars = $10.00 
Price in Reals = R$20.00

Visitor A 
Location: U.S
Product Price: $10.00 

Visitor B
Location: Brazil
Product Price: R$20.00
```

Have someone a answer for this? If it needs override or exists a plugin or something like that I can use, I'd appreciate some help.

**Note:** I'm learning english, so I ask to try to understand, I really worked too hard to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Virtuemart. we had Currency converter modules.
if you use currency converter then you can had the option to number of countries currency to show.

that's good to see.

use it. then you can get the good result.

Comment: Kumar thanks for the help, I got an answer in the virtuemart forum, in april,  I resolved this with a menu item with a external/internal link type where I put a parameter in my custom link called virtuemart_currency_id, and I put the currency id value from the currencies table in mysql database, to change by language, I've created two menus, one for english and other for portuguese, in Brazil I put the brazilian real as a value for parameter and for U.S the american dolar.

Comment: There's a example here: index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_cat‌​‌​egory_id=1&virtuem‌​ar‌​t_currency_id=20‌​&vir‌​tuemart_manufa‌​cturer‌​_id=0&catego‌​rylayout‌​=0&showcat‌​egory=1&pr‌​oductsub‌​layout=0

Comment: I not sure if the currency converter module of virtuemart 3x, works very well, I tested it too, but with me not worked pretty well.